# php cookies not read until form submitted

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am having an issue where cookies that are being set are not being read until I submit the page, even on return visits to the page.

Basically, I have a small form on a page. After the page has been submitted and processes 2 cookies are set. The first expires with the browser session and tells the page to display a thank you message, the second expires in one month and tells the page to show another message. If the appropriate cookies are not found, the page defaults to showing the form.

Above the `DOCTYPE` I have the following code which looks for the cookies and sets a variable to display the correct page

```
$display = $DISPLAY_FORM;

if ((!empty($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_RETURN])) && ($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_RETURN] == $COOKIE_RETURN))
{
    // If a return visitor, show DISPLAY_HIDDEN
    $display = $DISPLAY_HIDDEN;
}
if ((!empty($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_REG])) && ($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_REG] == $COOKIE_REG))
{
    // If a new registration, show DISPLAY_THANKS
    $display = $DISPLAY_THANKS;
}
```

Following that there is the logic that checks and processes the form. If everything is correct, it will set the 2 cookies and set the `$display` variable to `$DISPLAY_THANKS`

```
setcookie($COOKIE_REG, $COOKIE_REG, 0, "/");
setcookie($COOKIE_RETURN, $COOKIE_RETURN, strtotime("+1 month"), "/");

$display = $DISPLAY_THANKS;
```

The code is being run in a subdirectory, so from my understanding using the `"/"` path should make the cookie visible to the entire site. `$COOKIE_REG` should set a cookie with the same name and value, which should expire when the browser is closed. `$COOKIE_RETURN` should set a cookie with the same name and value and should expire in 1 month.

This is all before the `DOCTYPE` element, and no errors are thrown when the cookies are being set. In the page `BODY` there is a simple php `if` statement which checks the `$display` variable to see which state to display.

When I use the page first time through I see the form. I fill in the form, submit and the page returns to the thank you message. All is well. However, if I click to another page on the site and then navigate in to the cookie page again, I am presented with the form, not the thank you message. If I close the browser (which should end the first cookie) and return to the page, I once again get the form.

From this it looks like the cookies are not being set. However, before the `setcookie` code and cookie reading `if` statements, I added `echo print_r($_COOKIE, true);`. On the first visit to my page, the expected cookies were not visible, however when I submit the form they are there. The cookies are not being set on this submit as:

1. The code is echoing out the `print_r`, so the header has already been sent and therefore cannot write a new cookie (I get the error message to confirm this).
2. Even if the code was outputting a cookie, it would not appear in the `$_COOKIE` array until the next visit to the page.

The first time through `print_r` returns

```
Array
(
    [17a7190f9ad90db58025cb2dea23788f] => 73fcd0caf5e997e47097a4eade799c59
)
```

The second time, after submitting the form it returns

```
Array
(
    [returnVisitor] => returnVisitor
)
```

Any help would be great.

--- EDIT - Main code body added below ---

```
<?php
// These variables define what is displayed on the page.
$DISPLAY_HIDDEN = 0;
$DISPLAY_FORM = 1;
$DISPLAY_THANKS = 2;

// This variable is where the display type is set, it defaults to show the form
$display = $DISPLAY_FORM;

// Cookie variables
$COOKIE_REG = "formComplete";
$COOKIE_RETURN = "returnVisitor";

// echo print_r($_COOKIE, true);

// Check for a cookie to see if the form has been completed already.
// If there is a cookie, check to see if it's a new registration cookie or a return visitor
if ((!empty($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_REG])) && ($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_REG] == $COOKIE_REG))
{
    // If a new registration, show DISPLAY_THANKS
    $display = $DISPLAY_THANKS;
}
else if ((!empty($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_RETURN])) && ($_COOKIE[$COOKIE_RETURN] == $COOKIE_RETURN))
{
    // If a return visitor, show DISPLAY_HIDDEN
    $display = $DISPLAY_HIDDEN;
}   
// If no cookie exists, check to see if the form has been submitted
else if ( !empty($_REQUEST['formSubmit']) )
{
    // -- REMOVED FOR STACK OVERFLOW - Processes form data --

    // Create and set 2 cookies
    // Cookie 1: Expires when the browser closes and is for new registrants
    setcookie($COOKIE_REG, $COOKIE_REG, 0, "/");
    // Cookie 2: Expires in a month and is for returning visitors
    setcookie($COOKIE_RETURN, $COOKIE_RETURN, strtotime("+1 month"), "/");

    // Set the page to display the thanks screen
    $display = $DISPLAY_THANKS;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
  <head>
-- REMOVED FOR STACK OVERFLOW --
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php if ($display == $DISPLAY_FORM) { ?>
      --- REMOVED FOR STACK OVERFLOW - This is where the form is drawn. ---
    <?php } else if ($display == $DISPLAY_THANKS) { ?>
      --- REMOVED FOR STACK OVERFLOW - This is where the thank you message is drawn. ---
    <?php } else if ($display == $DISPLAY_HIDDEN) { ?>
      --- REMOVED FOR STACK OVERFLOW - This is where the returning visitor message is drawn. ---
    <?php } // endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Expected behaviour

#### First visit to page

No cookies are set and the form has not been submitted, so the default option of displaying the form is used. ***works as expected***

#### Second visit to page via form submit

No cookies are set, but the form has been submitted. The form data is processed, the cookies are set, and the internal `$display` variable is told to display the thank you message. ***appears to work as expected***

#### Subsequent visits to the page up until the browser is closed

The `$COOKIE_REG` cookie is found, which sets the `$display` variable to show the thank you page.

#### Subsequent visits to the page, after the browser has been closed

If within 1 month of the form being submitted, the `$COOKIE_RETURN` cookie should be found and the `$DISPLAY_HIDDEN` page should be drawn.
If 1 month has passed, the page should be treated as if it is the first visit.

Comment: Use $_SESSION instead of $_COOKIE for the info you want to store that expires with the browser session. Scanning over your problem it looks like it is because cookies are set at the end of the page, so they only appear on the next refresh. $_SESSION will be set straight away

Comment: I'm expecting the cookie not to work for the first and second time the page is viewed, which is why I'm handling the display with a variable. The problem is that from the third page view, the cookies that have been set are not being picked up.

As neither cookie is working as expected, I'd rather just try to get both cookies working, as even if I used the session for one cookie, the problem would still exist with the other.

Comment: Any chance we can get a look at more of the code? It is easier for a lot of developers (such as myself) to read code than it is to read comments and descriptions around code. Also, the output you are getting along with the output you expect.

Comment: I'll amend the main post to include the main body of the code. I'll take out parts that are not relevent to save on space.